# How do I get a popup window to open upon interacting with an EditText?

Tags: android, popupwindow

I want a popup window to open when a user opens an EditText for editing. Here's my basic code for it.

```
toDate.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            initiatePopupWindow();
            return false;
        }
    });
}


protected void initiatePopupWindow() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    try {
        popDate = (LayoutInflater) TripData.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View layout = popDate.inflate(R.layout.popdate, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.popup));

        datePw = new PopupWindow(layout, 300, 370, true);
        datePw.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

toDate being the EditText. I know the problem is that I have no action specified. My problem is, I don't know how to specify the action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean with "when a user opens an EditText for editing"? If you mean that the action should perform when the EditText becomes "active", then you might probably want:

[setOnFocusChangeListener() reference page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnFocusChangeListener%28android.view.View.OnFocusChangeListener%29)

Hope this helps

Comment: That's is exactly what I meant. Thanks.